# About creating projects in QT

Tags: c#, c++, python, objective-c, c

I installed Qt 2.8.1, in creating project list i don't find the "Applications" nor "libraries", this is the list:

Empty project
Non-Qt project
Import projects

Anyone can help ?

Answer (score 1):

Thr ***.pro file will be present for the project. You can specify "TEMPLATE = app" for application and if for a dll you can mention as "TEMPLATE = lib"